# VBA TO copy text from textbox into slideTitle

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have created a  macro in Powerpoint that will search for slides that are using a textbox for their title and are replacing them with a Title box. The steps are

1) find the slides that have a textbox in the title area
2) Copy the text in the textbox to a variable called slTitle.
3) Delete the texbox
4) Create a Title Holder for the current slide
5) Copy the text into the Title holder
6) Move on to the next slide

My macro currently is able to get as far as step 4 but I can't figure out how to get the text in `slTitle` into the Title box. This should be fairly easy to do but I've tried several ways and nothing seems to work.  If anyone can help me figure out this step it would be much appreciated.

I am getting a compile error  "Invalid Qualifier" on the line:

```
Set ppPlaceholderTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = slTitle
```

Here is my current macro.

```
Sub AddMiMissingTitles()

Dim shpCurrShape As Object
Dim x As Integer
Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim sld As Slide
Dim ctr As Integer
Dim s As Shape


'x = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
'counter ctr used to count number of slides that needed titles added
ctr = 0

 '**************************************************************
 Set sourcePres = ActivePresentation

    x = 1 ' slide counter

    'get the title text
    For Each sl In sourcePres.Slides

            'delete all the empty title text boxes first
            For Each s In sl.Shapes

             If s.Top < 45 Then ' it's in the title area
                 'MsgBox s.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                 If s.Type <> ppPlaceholderTitle Then ' it isn't a proper Title placeholder
                      If s.HasTextFrame = msoTrue Then
                          If Trim(s.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) = "" Then
                              s.Delete ' delete empty text holders
                          Else
                              slTitle = s.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                              s.Delete
                              sl.CustomLayout = sl.CustomLayout 'reset the slide
                              Set ppPlaceholderTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = slTitle
                              End If
                      End If
                  End If
             End If

           Next





             'Is there a title placeholder on the current layout?
             If sl.CustomLayout.Shapes.HasTitle Then
                 lngType = sl.CustomLayout.Shapes.Title.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                 '*********************************
               '  With ActivePresentation.Slides()


             End If
Next
 MsgBox "Done! " & vbCrLf & ctr & " Slides needed Titles."
                 '*********************************
                 'sl.Shapes.AddPlaceholder lngType
                 sl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange = slTitle
  End Sub
```

Comment: There may be other issues, but my guess is that the line you mention doesn't need the word `set` at the beginning. There are probably more techically correct ways to say this but: `set` is for allocating of objects to variables, here you are allocating a value to a property of an object.

Comment: `ppPlaceholderTitle` is a type. it is actually a number (=1). Look at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745779.aspx). Basically now you are typing `Set 1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = slTitle`. Add a placeholder which its type is `ppPlaceholderTitle`.